# How to reset a C++ vector of built-ins with zeros?

Tags: c++, vector

If efficency is an issue and I need vectors, what should I use?

```
assert(myVector.size() == wantedSize)
memset(&*myVector.begin(),0,myVector.size() * sizeof(T)); 

myVector.clear(); 
myVector.resize(wantedSize); 

myVector.clear(); 
myVector.assign(wantedSize,0);
```

I can assume that wantedSize = size()

Comment: Don't use `memset` for `std::vector`.

Comment: @MM.: When you say "don't do something", normally it makes sense to explain **WHY**. In case of std::vector memset will work. However mixing C/C++ routines is considered bad taste and there's already std::fill.

Comment: What makes you think that in `vector` every element is strictly next to each other? With `memset` you are probably wrecking havoc with it now. Moreover if you have a class of size `sizeof(T)` you can't just write zeros all over it. Especially if it has virtuals. @SigTerm I'm, pretty sure you can make an example where it does not work.

Comment: std::vector guarantees entries are contiguous. Except for bools.

Comment: @luk32: "What makes you think" **It is a required by C++ standard**. Go ahead and read it. 23.2.4.1 in C++03. *"The elements of a
vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if v is a vector<T, Allocator> where T is some type
other than bool, then it obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size()"* "Especially if it has virtuals." ints and basic types - the ones op is talking about - have no virtuals.

Comment: @luk32: "I'm, pretty sure you can make an example" On standard-compliant compiler, and with primitive types (which is what op requested) you can't make such example.

Comment: @SigTerm Where did OP assume it? Maybe I'm, stupid but I believe `myVector.size() == wantedSize` is too weak.

Comment: @luk32: "vector of built-ins".

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not actually guaranteed by the C++ standard for all builtin types that setting all bits zero is the same as assigning 0. For integer types it's guaranteed but not for floating point or pointer types. Although not guaranteed, I'm pretty sure it is true in all current implementations, and for floating types you're OK if your implementation uses IEEE 754 representation. Still, there is a reason to prefer `fill` over `memset` beyond just a fear of C functions, which is guaranteed correctness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've missed one:

```
std::fill(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), 0);
```

instead of doing `memset`.

And it's the most efficient because it doesn't cause reallocations. No reallocations also means no iterator invalidation, which is IMO safer.

`std::fill` is also type-safe and is the one generally recommended for filling standard containers (not just `std::vector`!). Also more flexible as you can provide a value of another type other than the container's `value_type` as long as the provided value is convertible to that `value_type`.

Comment: `clear()` followed by `resize()` or `assign()` is also guaranteed to cause no reallocations, since `clear()` doesn't affect the capacity. It does invalidate iterators, of course.

Comment: @SteveJessop Ah. I get that. But a one-liner almost always beat other solutions. ;-)

Comment: Well, actually two, I confess. `#include <algorithm>`. :P